# Вызов конструктора без аргументов?

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, объявление

Здравствуйте. Решаю **2 задачу 9 главы** из книги **Р. Лафоре**. Наткнулся на проблему.
Задача:
Вспомните пример STRCONV из главы 8. Класс `String` в этом примере имеет дефект: у него нет защиты на тот случай, если его объекты будут инициализированы слишком длинной строкой (константа `size` имеет значение 15). Например: `String s = "Эта строка имеет очень большую длину и мы можем быть уверены, что она не уместится в отведенный буфер, что приведет к непредсказуемым последствиям.";` будет причиной переполнения массива `str` строкой `s` с непредсказуемыми последствиями вплоть до краха системы. Создадим класс `Pstring`, производный от класса `String`, в котором предотвратим возможность переполнения буфера при определении слишком длинной строковой константы. Новый конструктор производного класса будет копировать в `str` только `size-1` символов, если строка окажется слишком длинной, и будет копировать строку полностью, если она будет иметь длину меньшую, чем `size`. Напишите функцию `main()` программы для проверки ее работы со строками разной длины.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

const int size = 15;

class String {
protected:
    char str[size];
public:
    String () {
        str[0] = '\x0';
    }
    String (const char* s) {
        strcpy(str, s);
        std::cout << "Скопировано: " << str << std::endl;
    }
    void display () const {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
    operator char* () {
        return str;
    }
};

class Pstring : public String {
public:
    Pstring (char* s) {
        if (strlen(s) >= size) {
            for (int index = 0; index < size - 1; ++index) {
                str[index] = s[index];
            }
            str[strlen(str)] = '\x0';
        }
        else {
            String(s); // почему не копируется строка, а вызывается конструктор без аргументов?
            }
    }
};

int main () {
Pstring p1 = "pointers is evil!!!";
p1.display ();
Pstring p2 = "char * is bad";
p2.display();

return 0;
}
```

При определении переменных класса Pstring вначале вызывается конструктор по умолчанию **String::String();** до выполнения блока. Далее, идёт проверка на длину строки. Вопрос: Почему, если строка меньшего размера, то  при вызове конструктора **String(s);** в ветви else не копируется значение строки? Почему на выводе пустая строка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас имеется несколько проблем с определением конструкторов в классе `Pstring`. Во-первых, желательно, чтобы он вел себя как класс `String`, что означает, что он также должен иметь конструктор по умолчанию.

```
Pstring() {}
```

Во-вторых, вами определенный конструктор с параметром полностью неверный.

В этом предложении конструктора

```
str[strlen(str)] = '\x0';
```

присутствуют сразу же две ошибки. Строка `str` не имеет пока еще завершающего нуля, поэтому вызов `strlen( str )` ведет к неопределенному поведению. К тому же вы должны установить в 0 символ в позиции `size - 1`

В этом предложении

```
String(s);
```

У вас создается временный объект, который сразу же удаляется в конце предложения. Он никак не связан с тем объектом, в конструкторе которого вызывается это предложение.

Имейте в виду, что когда вы имеете дело со строками, а тем более со стандартными C функциями, предназначенными для работы со строками, то лучше в качестве индекса в строках использовать тип `size_t`  вместо типа `int`.

Также в качестве параметра конструктора следует задать параметр с типом `const char *`, так как, как по крайней мере следует из вашей программы, конструктор может иметь дело со строковыми литералами в качестве аргументов, а строковые литералы в C++ в выражениях преобразуются (за редким исключением) к типу `const char *`.

Далее длина члена класса `str` - это внутреннее свойство самого класса. Поэтому его длина не должна быть глобальной переменной.

И, наконец, желательно, чтобы деструктор был виртуальным.

Я бы определили данные классы следующим образом

```
class String {
protected:
    static const size_t size = 15;
    char str[size];

public:
    String () {
        str[0] = '\x0';
    }
    String (const char* s) {
        std::strcpy(str, s);
        std::cout << "Скопировано: " << str << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~String() {}
    void display () const {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
    operator const char* () const {
        return str;
    }
};

class Pstring : public String {
public:
    Pstring() {}
    Pstring ( const char* s) {
        if ( std::strlen(s) < size) {
            std::strcpy( str, s );
        }
        else {
            size_t i = 0;
            for ( ; i < size - 1; ++i) {
                str[i] = s[index];
            }
            str[i] = '\x0';
            // или просто 
            //std::strncpy( str, s, size - 1 );
            // str[size-1] = '\0';   
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

У вас здесь

```
String(s);
```

просто объявление переменной `s` типа `String`. Естественно, для нее вызывается конструктор по умолчанию.

Вы не можете просто взять и вызвать конструктор посреди другой функции, как обычную функцию.

Перепишите свой конструктор как

```
Pstring(const char* s)
{
    if (s) 
    {
        strncpy(str,s,size-1);
        str[size-1] = 0;
    }
}
```

При `s==nullptr` я ничего не делаю, потому что конструктор базового класса по умолчанию уже зануляет первый символ.

Кстати, рекомендовал бы и в `String` делать соответствующую проверку.